# Genymotion android emulator show many log

Tags: android, logcat, genymotion

I am using Genymotion emulator in eclipse but logcat show many log same this :

```
?:??: W/?(?): [ 08-28 03:42:39.957   317:  344 E/Genymotion ]
```

and this

```
?:??: W/?(?): [ 08-28 03:42:37.061   396:  396 D/OpenGLRenderer ]

?:??: W/?(?): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7d80b58): name, size, mSize = 15, 1440,
```

and ..
how can I filter this logs or remove same logs from logcat?
thank you?

Answer (score 2):

After trying to connect a 4.2.2 device for debugging, I have solved these ?s.
What I do is update my ADT, Android-SDK & Genymotion to the latest version.
Good luck!

Only after this, you will see that what's that logs. It's normal for both physical devices and emulators.

P.S. 
Screenshot of logcat with genymotion ignored for "You need at least 10 reputation to post images" :(